Minimum number of measurements required to find heaviest and lightest from a group of idetntical looking balls having distinct weights.
You are given 68 identical looking balls, each with a distinct weight. You are given a common balance using which you can compare weights of any two pair of balls with a single measurement. Describe how you would identify both the heaviest and the lightest balls by using at most 100 measurements in total.

What is the source of this problem?

What have you thought yourself about this?
